# Kubernetes master is returning 401 Unauthorized error

Tags: kubernetes, minikube, kubernetes-apiserver

I have installed minikube, kubectl  in my laptop.

When I run `kubectl cluster-info` in get the below

```
   Kubernetes master is running at https://10.168.99.10:8443
```

when I connect to  https://10.168.99.10:8443 I get the below response.

```
{
  "kind": "Status",
  "apiVersion": "v1",
  "metadata": {

  },
  "status": "Failure",
  "message": "Unauthorized",
  "reason": "Unauthorized",
  "code": 401
}
```

When installed kubectl/minikube didn't prompt for user/password.
What is the default user/password to connect.

Comment: How do you try to connect apisever in minikube? from browser or from terminal?

Comment: hi aerokite - I'm using browser

Comment: Did you try my 2nd option.  Proxy. ?

Comment: No, not yet I will try now what you've suggested and let you know.

Comment: Did you you solve your problem?

Answer (score 3):

**minikube** doesn't start with basic-auth. So there is not username & password for apiserver by default. To access apiserver, you need to use apiserver certificates. That`s how you will be authorized.

```
curl https://192.168.99.100:8443 --cert ~/.minikube/apiserver.crt  --key ~/.minikube/apiserver.key --cacert ~/.minikube/ca.crt
```

**See details:**

Get your minikube IP address

```
$ minikube ip
192.168.99.100
```

The API server runs on `8443` by default

Now try to connect apiserver using this

```
$ curl https://192.168.99.100:8443  
curl: (60) SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate
```

Need to provide CA certificate

```
$ curl https://192.168.99.100:8443  --cacert ~/.minikube/ca.crt 
{
  "kind": "Status",
  "apiVersion": "v1",
  "metadata": {

  },
  "status": "Failure",
  "message": "Unauthorized",
  "reason": "Unauthorized",
  "code": 401
}⏎
```

Now you need to provide apiserver SSL certificate and key

```
curl https://192.168.99.100:8443 --cert ~/.minikube/apiserver.crt  --key ~/.minikube/apiserver.key --cacert ~/.minikube/ca.crt 
{
  "paths": [
    "/api",
    "/api/v1",
    ....
    "/ui",
    "/ui/",
    "/version"
  ]
}⏎
```

> Note: You can proxy apiserver too

```
$ kubectl proxy --port=8433
$ curl 127.0.0.1:8433
```

Now you do not need to provide any certificates. And you are authorized

Comment: If you use browser, search how to add certificate in browser. It will work

Answer (score 0):

Please trying to put `kubectl proxy --address=clusterIP --port 8001 --accept-hosts '.*'`, then you can browse it at http://localhost:8001.

Answer (score -2):

Looks like you are doing `curl https://10.168.99.10:8443 -k`. There is no need to do it. Infact, the response you are seeing is expected as you are not authenticating to kubernetes.

1. Do `minikube dashboard` to open the kubernetes dashboard. This will use the `NodePort` of the `kubernetes-dashboard` service and open the kubernetes dashboard GUI in a browser.
2. Minikube creates `kubeconfig` at `~/.kube/config` on the laptop. So, just use `kubectl` to use k8s in Minikube.
3. The `kubectl` configuration can be viewed by doing `kubectl config view` on the laptop.